# Не запускается демон docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина?

```
   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status docker
        ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
           Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
           Active: activating (start) since Sat 2020-07-04 09:59:46 UTC; 4min 28s ago
             Docs: https://docs.docker.com
         Main PID: 2564 (dockerd)
              CPU: 53.595s
           CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
                   ├─2564 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
                   └─2570 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
    
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: r8      0x769149a4
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: r9      0x34
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: r10     0x13200540
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: fp      0x28f7210
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: ip      0x20
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: sp      0x76914890
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: lr      0xffffffff
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: pc      0x76c8645c
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: cpsr    0x10
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: fault   0x0
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xn
    -- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 17:16:42 UTC, end at Sat 2020-07-04 10:04:14 UTC. --
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: fp      0x28f7210
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: ip      0x20
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: sp      0x76914890
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: lr      0xffffffff
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: pc      0x76c8645c
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: cpsr    0x10
    июл 04 09:59:46 raspberrypi dockerd[2344]: fault   0x0
    июл 04 10:04:14 raspberrypi sudo[2588]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status docker
    июл 04 10:04:14 raspberrypi sudo[2588]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
    июл 04 10:04:14 raspberrypi sudo[2588]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root



Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:210
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: created by github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).restore
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:210 +0xbc0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: goroutine 1024 [runnable]:
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: syscall.Syscall6(0x142, 0xffffff9c, 0x1aa25a00, 0xa00c2, 0x180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12, 0x1aa25a00, 0x0)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/usr/local/go/src/syscall/asm_linux_arm.s:48 +0x8
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: syscall.openat(0xffffff9c, 0x1aa25980, 0x79, 0xa00c2, 0x180, 0x8753ec, 0x1aa25980, 0x79)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_arm.go:38 +0x7c
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: syscall.Open(0x1aa25980, 0x79, 0x800c2, 0x180, 0x877a44, 0x1a56ac90, 0x2)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/usr/local/go/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go:51 +0x40
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: os.OpenFile(0x1aa25980, 0x79, 0xc2, 0x180, 0x79, 0x1abb55a0, 0x1d)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:158 +0x70
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: io/ioutil.TempFile(0x1a63d3b0, 0x5b, 0x1a56acc8, 0x14, 0xf, 0x1a56acc8, 0x14)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/tempfile.go:55 +0x104
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/pkg/ioutils.NewAtomicFileWriter(0x1a63d3b0, 0x6b, 0x1a4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x203d048, 0x1a3f8000)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/ioutils/fswriters.go:14 +0x9c
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/container.(*Container).WriteHostConfig(0x14bb5a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/container/container.go:253 +0x8c
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/container.(*Container).toDisk(0x14bb5a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/container/container.go:193 +0x204
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/container.(*Container).CheckpointTo(0x14bb5a40, 0x2951ab8, 0x14b6d620, 0x22646e69, 0x6f53222c)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/container/container.go:204 +0x1c
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).checkpointAndSave(0x14d960f0, 0x14bb5a40, 0x0, 0x0)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:1299 +0x80
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).restore.func1(0x1aa91bc0, 0x14d960f0, 0x1aa91b98, 0x17b9d980, 0x17b9d960, 0x17b9d940, 0x14bb5a40)
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:213 +0x70
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: created by github.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).restore
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: #011/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:210 +0xbc0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: trap    0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: error   0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: oldmask 0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r0      0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r1      0x769e4890
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r2      0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r3      0x8
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r4      0x0
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r5      0x769e4890
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r6      0x769e5370
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r7      0xaf
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r8      0x769e49a4
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r9      0x34
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: r10     0x14b00540
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: fp      0x292d210
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: ip      0x20
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: sp      0x769e4890
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: lr      0xffffffff
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: pc      0x76d5645c
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: cpsr    0x10
Jul  4 13:21:33 raspberrypi dockerd[27914]: fault   0x0
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.118086361Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.119630626Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.119852656Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.120384269Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.120742445Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.121188641Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.122458167Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Jul  4 13:21:35 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:35.126158361Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul  4 13:21:39 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:39.626414104Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 532f1c2d6b46560dc2ae96b786e8659a19693986b0a4e025529b714c61dffc9f: mount does not exist"
Jul  4 13:21:46 raspberrypi dockerd[28152]: time="2020-07-04T13:21:46.661991126Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount f44cf14b19ece2df2acf4850e7e05566948f2f3ae08da170fdee49cbeb486bae: mount does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. попробуй сначала включить cgroup, тк на контейнерах могут быть лимиты по ресурсам
   `sudo echo " cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1" >> /boot/cmdline.txt`
   посмотри  результат cat /proc/cgroups
2. похоже что контейнеры смотрели на недоступный сейчас volume,
   детали можно посмотреть в

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/532f1c2d6b46560dc2ae96b786e8659a19693986b0a4e025529b714c61dffc9f/hostconfig.json
/var/lib/docker/containers/f44cf14b19ece2df2acf4850e7e05566948f2f3ae08da170fdee49cbeb486bae/hostconfig.json
```